Get files from shared dropbox link (WPF)
I want to retrieve datas from shared Dropbox link and show them in a listview in my WPF project.

I looked throught the topics that were opened regarding this issue but i couldn’t find the solution.
I added DropboxApi nugget package and there are  many methods here.  I think one of them shows the files in the link.But i couldn’t find which one is.
Edit:
Thank you to those who replied, I changed the codes as you stated. But when I debug it, it never reaches the foreach line.
There are the codes:
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    GetFiles();
}

public async Task GetFiles()
{
   
    using (var dbx = new DropboxClient("accesstoken"))
    {
        var sharedLink = new SharedLink("https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fo/5hsaghkkzjubop56fhxhx/AN62TSoIVrO4U5yuTL2LRso?rlkey=1wj1yc2a8xaas8zug7cm95do3&e=1&dl=0");
        var sharedFiles = await dbx.Files.ListFolderAsync(path: "", sharedLink: sharedLink);
        
        foreach (var file in sharedFiles.Entries)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(file.ToString());
        }
    }
}


If you want this question reopened, please share more details.

This should work!
await dbx.Files.DownloadAsync(target_path);

Refer to the documentation here:
https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/dotnet#tutorial

.Wait() will block the UI thread. Better call await dbx.Files.DownloadAsync(target_path)

@Clemens Thx for the recommendation, I'd suggest the same. He's using a synchronous void method here.

The method signature should of course be public async Task GetFiles(), as usual.

If you want to list the contents of linked folder, you can use the Files ListFolderAsync method and pass the shared link in the sharedLink parameter.
If you want to download any particular file from the linked folder, you can use the SharingUserRoutes GetSharedLinkFileAsync method and pass the shared link in the url parameter and the file's sub-path (relative to the linked folder) in the path parameter.
